# Excel VBA create hyperlink of existing cell based on value above cell

Tags: vba, excel

I currently have a sheet called Title Detail. On the sheet there are several values named Title. Under each cell with the string "Title" I would like to create a hyperlink to that same cell.

I'm extremely new to VBA, and attempting to teach myself so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can give you a few tips. You have to know how to declare a range that includes all the cells you want to look for "Title" in. Then you can for example use 'For Each' loop to go through all these cells (in that defined range) and check if their value is "Title". If it is, then you can use Offset Property to go one cell down and put that hyperlink in it.

You can start with this:

https://www.excel-easy.com/vba/loop.html

https://www.excel-easy.com/vba/if-then-statement.html

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range(object)

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.value

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.formula

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.offset